# Почему не растягивается грид строчка по вертикали? В чем логика?

Tags: html, css, scss, css-grid, grid

Не срабатывает настойка рядов,занимаемых элементом в случае,если элемент растянут на всю ширину экрана и не указаны никакие настройки высоты для гридконтейнера. ***Файлы с кодом в конце. Скриншоты в спойлерах.***

1. примерно так и надо,как видите один блок занимает больше места по вертикали.[image]
2. НО.стоит его растянуть фулл по горизонтали,и это уже не работает. [image]
3. Добавляем значeние grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto); к гридконтейнеру,блок опять начинает занимать как надо,2 элемента. [image] 
   **Главное для меня сейчас - понять логику этого. Понять,почему так происходит. Надеюсь вы сможете помощь.**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YERSpy-2Z3a1SCHba3TSLiDRXWftXuAJ/view?usp=sharing - **Линк на архив с файлами**

Comment: Добавь [mcve] в вопрос.

Comment: @G H Есть у меня для вас игра, советую пройти, а не посмотреть и пройти мимо. https://cssgridgarden.com/#ru  Вода -ваша сетка - морковка, место куда сетку нужно поставить/сделать

Comment: спасибо,попробую